# Equality of Hausdorff dimension

Tags: real-analysis, hausdorff-measure

**Definitions:** Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R.}$
Define the **diameter** of $A$ by 
$$|A| = \sup_{x,y\in A}|x-y|.$$

For $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ with $|A|<\infty$ and $\alpha>0,$ define the **$\alpha$-cover length of $A$** by 
$$H_\alpha(A) = \inf\bigg\{ \sum_{n=1}^\infty |S_n|^\alpha:\{S_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \text{ is a countable cover of }A \bigg\}.$$
The **Haudorff dimension of $A$** is defined by 
$$\dim_H(A)=\inf \{\alpha >0:H_\alpha(A)=0\}.$$

..............................................................................................................................................................

In class, we have proven that 
$$\dim_H(A) = \sup\{\alpha\geq 0:H_\alpha(A)>0\}.$$

> **Question:** To prove $\dim_H(A) = c\in\mathbb{R},$ is it enough to prove that there exists ***a single*** countable cover such that $H_\alpha(A)>0$ if $\alpha<c, H_\alpha(A)=0$ if $\alpha>c?$

For example, let us consider the following propostion.

> **Proposition:** Let $C$ be the [Cantor Middle Third set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set). 
>   Prove that 
>   $$\dim_H(C)=\log_32.$$

To prove the above proposition, one can let $\alpha = \log_32$ and consider $\alpha'>\alpha.$
For $n\geq 1,$ let $I_1,...,I_{2^n}$ be the set of subintervals that made up of $C_n,$ where 
$$C=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty C_n.$$
Clearly $\{I_1,...,I_{2^n}\}$ is a cover for $C.$
Note that 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2^n}|I_k|^{\alpha'} = \sum_{k=1}^{2^n}(3^{-n})^{\alpha'} = 2^n(3^{-n\alpha'}) = e^{n(\ln 2-\alpha' \ln3)} = e^{n \ln 3(\alpha - \alpha')}.$$
Since $\alpha - \alpha' <0,$ as $n\to\infty,$ the above sum tends to $0.$
So it implies that 
$$\dim_H(C) \leq \log_32.$$

After this, one needs to prove that $\dim_H(C)\geq \log_32$ also holds.

But by using supremum definition of $\dim_H(C)$ and the cover $\{I_1,...,I_{2^n}\},$ can we conclude that 
$$\dim_H(C) = \log_32?$$

More precisely, for any $\alpha<\alpha',$ one can use the same cover and calculation above to obtain
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2^n}|I_k|^{\alpha'} = e^{n\ln 3(\alpha-\alpha')}.$$
Since $\alpha-\alpha'>0,$ therefore 
$$\dim_H(C) \geq \log_32.$$

Answer (score 1):

No, a single cover won't do. In order to show that $\dim_H (C) \geq \log_3 2$ using the result proved in class you have to show that $H_{\alpha} (C) >0$ for some $\alpha  \geq \log_3 2$ and  $H_{\alpha} (C) $ is defined as an infimum over all covers. For this you have to consider an arbitrary cover.